# Pulleys to make energy?

Tags: power-generation

Would it be possible to use several pulleys so a smaller motor could cause a larger motor to spin, thus causing more electricity to be outputted than there was inputted.

Looking at some high school level physics classes, it appears pulleys can be used to reduce the amount of newtons required to lift an object. So surely with enough pulleys (perhaps with a generator attached to each one to generate electricity) this is possible?

Thank you

Comment: Two things. You can’t get more energy out than you put in (at best you can break even), and with the inevitable  losses in the real world you can’t even break even.

Comment: @hacktastical I know about this, but surely this system above breaks that law?

Comment: You are forgetting pulleys change speed and force, not just force. Just like levers.

Comment: No, the system will obey the laws of thermodynamics. You can’t get out more electricity (energy) than you put in. You need to work on the units - newtons are force, not energy.

Comment: @hacktastical Are there any exceptions to when thermodynamics do not apply? Just any examples you have.

Comment: @securityauditor (classical) thermodynamics apply in the limit of large numbers of interacting particles. When one is not at the classical thermodynamic limit, thermodynamics is not a good model, but conservation of energy is still predicted by the underlying theories.

Comment: Not really an electrical engineering question. Try searching in physics stack exchange. This question probably has been asked already.

Comment: This sounds similar to Feynman's example of a mechanical (pulley-based) weight-lifting perpetual motion machine... https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77713/128537

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just another poorly thought out perpetual motion machine.

Comment: You forgot the basic of pulleys and gears. Energy transferred is the same assuming no losses on the way. You gotta spend same amount of net energy on all small motors to get back the same amount of energy from big motor.

Comment: **breaks that law**.  You accept it as a law, but you are looking for exceptions.  If there were exceptions, the laws of thermodynamics would not be laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any arrangement of pulleys that allows a small force to lift a large weight (i.e. one that provides a mechanical advantage) will require the small force to be applied over a proportionally longer distance.

For example the small motor could apply 1 N, pulling 10 m of cable through the pulleys. At the other end this could apply 10 N of force to the big motor, but it would only pull 1 m of cable.

Since work done is equal to force times the distance of the motion, the net result is that the energy expended by the small motor is equal (neglecting friction losses) to the energy delivered to the big motor.

The same is true for all the so-called "simple machines". Whether you use pulleys, gears, levers, incline planes, wedges, or screws, if a weak force on the input side of the machine is generating a strong force on the output side, the thing applying the input force will have to move proportionally farther than the object being moved by the machine.

Comment: Input: 1N pulls 10m of cable. Why is the output 1m of cable?

Comment: @securityauditor, draw a system of pulleys that provides a mechanical advantage of 10x and you will see.

Comment: If you could set up the pulleys to pull apart an atom, then you might have something.